# 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using the following code in my django app which is working fine if I use it as it is but when I extend the base to the following html it throws the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is
>   missing or has been tampered with']

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>gffdfdf</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.formset.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <form id="myForm" action="" method="post" class="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2> Team</h2>
        {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}  {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form.player.management_form }}

        <h3> Product Instance(s)</h3>
        <table id="table-product" class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>player name</th>
                <th>highest score</th>
                <th>age</th>
            </tr>

            </thead>
            {% for player in form.player %}
            <tbody class="player-instances">

            <tr>
                <td>{{ player.pname }}</td>
                <td>{{ player.hscore }}</td>
                <td>{{ player.age }}</td>
                <td><input id="input_add" type="button" name="add" value=" Add More "
                           class="tr_clone_add btn data_input"></td>

            </tr>

            </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>

    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var i = 1;
    $("#input_add").click(function () {
        $("tbody tr:first").clone().find(".data_input").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('class') == 'tr_clone_add btn data_input') {
                $(this).attr({
                    'id': function (_, id) {
                        return "remove_button"
                    },
                    'name': function (_, name) {
                        return "name_remove" + i
                    },
                    'value': 'Remove'
                }).on("click", function () {
                    var a = $(this).parent();
                    var b = a.parent();
                    i = i - 1
                    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(i);
                    b.remove();

                    $('.player-instances tr').each(function (index, value) {
                        $(this).find('.data_input').each(function () {
                            $(this).attr({
                                'id': function (_, id) {
                                    console.log("id", id)
                                    var idData = id;
                                    var splitV = String(idData).split('-');
                                    var fData = splitV[0];
                                    var tData = splitV[2];
                                    return fData + "-" + index + "-" + tData
                                },
                                'name': function (_, name) {
                                    console.log("name", name)
                                    var nameData = name;
                                    var splitV = String(nameData).split('-');
                                    var fData = splitV[0];
                                    var tData = splitV[2];
                                    return fData + "-" + index + "-" + tData
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    })
                })
            } else {
                $(this).attr({
                    'id': function (_, id) {
                        console.log("id", id)

                        var idData = id;
                        var splitV = String(idData).split('-');
                        var fData = splitV[0];
                        var tData = splitV[2];
                        return fData + "-" + i + "-" + tData
                    },
                    'name': function (_, name) {
                        console.log("name", name)

                        var nameData = name;
                        var splitV = String(nameData).split('-');
                        var fData = splitV[0];
                        var tData = splitV[2];
                        return fData + "-" + i + "-" + tData
                    }
                });

            }
        }).end().appendTo("tbody");
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(1 + i);
        $("tbody tr:last :input").each(function () {
            $(this).attr({
                'id': function (_, id) {
                    return id.replace(/\d/g, i)
                },
                'name': function (_, name) {
                    return name.replace(/\d/g, i)
                },
            })
        })

        i++;

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code I am adding to it:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
..The above code
{% endblock %}
```

Why is it happening ?

Forms.py

```
class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'

PlayerFormset= formset_factory(PlayerForm)

class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

   player= PlayerFormset()
   class Meta:
       model = Team
       fields = '__all__'
       exclude = ["player"]
```

Views.py

```
def post(request):

   if request.POST:
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        form.player_instances = PlayerFormset(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team= Team()
            team.tname= form.cleaned_data['tname']
            team.save()

        if form.player_instances.cleaned_data is not None:
            for item in form.player_instances.cleaned_data:
                player = Player()
                player.pname= item['pname']
                player.hscore= item['hscore']
                player.age= item['age']
                player.save()
                team.player.add(player)
            team.save()

   else:
        form = TeamForm()
        return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/new.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Can you share the form and view? Does it by any chance contain a `FileField` or `ImageField`?